# How to map my stream value to my object class

Tags: java, apache-kafka, stream

I do have a `Song.Class` (`song_id, song_name, song_duration`).
....

```
package org.example.demo.model;

public class Flux {
private int user_id;
private int song_id;
private float listening_duration;

public Flux(int user_id, int song_id, float listening_duration) {
    this.user_id = user_id;
    this.song_id = song_id;
    this.listening_duration = listening_duration;
}
```

...

I do have a first program to send some events to a kafka topic (serialize in Avro) :

```
props.put("key.serializer", StringSerializer.class.getName());
props.put("value.serializer", KafkaAvroSerializer.class.getName());
props.put("schema.registry.url","http://172.17.0.8:8081");
KafkaProducer<String, Flux> kafkaProducerFlux = new KafkaProducer<String, Flux>(props);
```

Witin a loop:

```
Flux flux = Flux.newBuilder()
.setSongId(arraysong.get(s).getSongId())
.setUserId(arrayuser.get(u).getUserId())
.setListeningDuration(arraysong.get(s).getSongDuration())
.build();

kafkaProducerFlux.send(new ProducerRecord<String, Flux>(topic_events, flux));
```

....

Now, I would like to get back my object in a stream as :

```
KStream<String, Flux> source = builder.stream("music_flux");
KStream<String, GenericRecord> source = builder.stream("music_flux");
```

To bet able to join the `user_id` with inputs from another streams.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Add some inputs here : https://blog.octo.com/en/confluent-io-part-3-stream-processing/
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure the key and value deserializer in the kafka stream properties. Since the Flux schema is written in schema registry via your Kafka producer, Kstream application will read the schema from there. You need to configure "**SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG**" and "**VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG**" as given below:

```
KStreamBuilder builder = new KStreamBuilder();

Properties props= new Properties();
// Set a few key parameters
props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "kafka-app-1");
props.put(StreamsConfig.KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
props.put(StreamsConfig.VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, SpecificAvroSerde.class);
props.put(AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, "http://172.17.0.8:8081");
StreamsConfig config = new StreamsConfig(props);

KStream<String, Flux> source = builder.stream("music_flux");
```

Comment: The Flux class isn't a SpecificRecord type, though